# For the common keys, how would you access the corresponding values

Tags: python, list, dictionary, key

```
def query_RR(postings, qtext): 
   words = tokenize(qtext) 
   allpostings = [postings[w] for w in words]
   for a in allpostings: 
       print a.keys()
```

And this was the result of the query

```
[0, 2, 3, 4, 6]
[1, 4, 5]
[0, 2, 4]
[4, 5]
```

The query is taking a user input term (`qtext`), tokenizing and generating a postings list for each token.

The posting list is a list of nested dictionaries.
e.g.

```
[{0 : 0.68426, 1: 0.26423}, {2: 0.6842332, 0: 0.9823}]
```

For the common keys, how would you access the corresponding values, for my example the common value is `0`so how would you access values `{0 : 0.68426, 0: 0.9823}`?

Comment: Will we miss anything if we start reading from *"The posting list..."*?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is one way:

```
lst = [{0: 0.68426, 1: 0.26423}, {2: 0.6842332, 0: 0.9823}] 

[d[0] for d in lst]       # [0.68426, 0.9823]
```

Or if you need a dictionary:

```
{0: [d[0] for d in lst]}  # {0: [0.68426, 0.9823]}
```

If you need to work out your common dictionary keys:

```
{i: [d[i] for d in lst] for i in set.intersection(*map(set, lst))}

# {0: [0.68426, 0.9823]}
```

Note that dictionary keys must be unique, so your required output is not possible.

Answer (score 0):

```
lst = [{0 : 0.68426, 1: 0.26423}, {2: 0.6842332, 0: 0.9823}]

res = {}
for x in lst:
    for key, value in x.items():
        if key in res:
            res[key].append(value)
        else:
            res[key] = [value]
```

This returns you a dictionary of the form `{0: [0.68426, 0.9823]}` because this `{0 : 0.68426, 0: 0.9823}` is not possible.